# Windows Phone map integration performance issue

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am creating Windows Phone 8 silverlight application and i am using map control with toolkit MapExtensions to bind the pins on the map. But when I navigate away from map screen or come back to this screen it takes normally 2 to 3 sec to load this page. Where as when application is navigating between other non map pages it is fast. How can i improve application performance regarding map load and unload time while navigation. Here is the map control code I am using:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map"
                      Center="{Binding CenterLocation,
                      Mode=TwoWay}"
                      CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                      ColorMode="Light"
                      Background="White"
                      >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ResolveCompleted">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MapResolveCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <tool:MapExtensions.Children>
                    <tool:UserLocationMarker GeoCoordinate="{Binding CurrentLocation,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             Width="50"
                                             Height="50"
                                             Style="{StaticResource LocationMapMarker}">

                    </tool:UserLocationMarker>

                    <tool:MapItemsControl Name="mapItems">
                        <tool:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <tool:MapChildControl GeoCoordinate="{Binding ItemLocation, Converter={StaticResource LocationToGeoCoordinateConverter}}">
                                    <tool:MapChildControl.Content>
                                        <Image

                                            Source="{Binding ItemId,
                                            Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
                                    </tool:MapChildControl.Content>
                                </tool:MapChildControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </tool:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </tool:MapItemsControl>
                </tool:MapExtensions.Children>
            </maps:Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. The map control is a pretty heavy control as there is a lot of moving parts to it. In addition to that, by putting it on a page, every time you move to the page the Map is recreated. What you can do is create a single map and reuse it across all the pages. I wrote a blog post on how to do this for Windows Store apps here: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/10/24/be-smooth-optimize-bing-maps-in-multipage-windows-store-apps-javascript/

This was for a JavaScript application so this only shows the concept and would take a decent amount of work to port over.

Comment: I do get your point.. but in my application I am using bing map at launch page and each time I come back to launch page there is a delay in navigation which doesn't give a good user experience... I just want to fix that.... How can I do that?